# How can I get around ref parameters not allowing type variation?

Tags: c#, class-design, covariance, contravariance, variance

Lets say I have the following class structure in my data access layer:

```
interface IBehavior<in T>
{
  void Load(T model);
}

class ModelManager<T>
{
  ModelManager(IEnumerable<IBehavior<T>> behaviors) { ... }

  void Load(T model)
  {
    foreach (var behavior in behaviors) {
      behavior.Load(model)
    }
  }
}
```

This lets me have various interfaces that my models can implement, and reusable behaviors that handle those interfaces:

```
interface IUnique { ... }
class UniqueBehavior : IBehavior<IUnique>  { ... }

interface ITimestampable  { ... }
class TimestampableBehavior : IBehavior<ITimestampable> { ... }
```

And the manager will gladly take these because of contravariance in `IBehavior<T>`.

```
class MyModel : IUnique, ITimestampable { ... }

new ModelManager<MyModel>(new IBehavior<MyModel>[] {
  new UniqueBehavior(),
  new TimestampableBehavior()
});
```

Super.

But now, I want to let each behavior apply a set of LINQ filters to the entity too. My first idea was to add this method to `IBehavior<T>`:

```
void ApplyFilters<IEnumerable>(ref IEnumerable<T> models)
```

... in which an implementing behavior would apply a set of `Where` clauses to the enumeration at its discretion.

However, as it turns out, [ref parameters don't allow type variation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/21/why-do-ref-and-out-parameters-not-allow-type-variation.aspx). I'm struggling to find a way to implement this kind of functionality while maintaining both type safety and the contravariant nature of the interface. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I would expect `ApplyFilters` to have the signature `IEnumerable<T> ApplyFilters(IEnumerable<T> models)`

Comment: Wouldn't work either, it makes T a return type. I remember trying both, and in my use case using ref makes more sense. This way, if the behaviour doesn't want to apply any filters, it can just leave the method blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this would work in your exact context, but have you tried making ApplyFolders generic itself?

```
void ApplyFolders<TEnum>(ref IEnumerable<TEnum> models) where TEnum : T;
```

Comment: That's so crazy that it works! Thank you, I wouldn't have thought of it myself.

Comment: You probably *don't* want a `ref` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at the [Ptr class](http://incrediblejourneysintotheknown.blogspot.com/2008/05/pointers-to-value-types-in-c.html). I've been taking advantage of this class recently to completely bust all of the limitations .NET puts on ref keywords to let me side effect objects the CLR for some reason feels I have no right to.

Comment: That's a great class, but it wouldn't work in this case because it doesn't go around the contravariance issue - the property would be both in and out.

Comment: The restrictions on `ref` are there to maintain type safety and verifiability; bear in mind that `ref` means the actual 'outer' variable is modified, not a copy, and you don't want the instance changed to something else by another thread underneath you...

Comment: @LLia and @thecoop using the PTR class let's you have ref usage that you can alter the underlying variable, without using the ref keyword. This class does indeed work. I use this to have ref usage inside a yield return method. Methods with yield return don't allow you to use ref variables.